# Workflow return to a specific stage

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

My scenario: Each time an item is created in a list, a mail is sent informing USER1 that the item was created.Now if user one approves the item,its moves to the next stage but if there is any error for correction a mail need to be send to one who created the item to modify the item.Again this item should go through the stage of approval.I am using a column name status to know if the item is approved or is missing info. Anyone can give me an idea how to implement that,i cant seem to be able to go back to the previous stage of approval if data is missing for the item.i am using SharePoint designer here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can create a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow and design it like the below:
[image]

For **Start Options**, you can set it like:
[image]